# How to share JUnit BeforeClass logic among multiple test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

Currently, all of my JUnit tests extend from a common base class that provides methods tagged with  `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations - all these really do is setup a bunch of static resources/services for the tests to use.

This seems a awkward to me for a few reasons:

1. Part of the point of JUnit4 (from my understanding) is that we shouldn't need this classical test inheritance anymore.
2. When I run these tests as part of a suite instead of individually (which we often do), the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` get invoked multiple times, slowing down the tests - we really should only be calling these once

What I'd like to do is somehow move the current BeforeClass/AfterClass logic out of the inheritance chain and into something that can be shared by individual tests and the suite as a whole.

**Can this be done? If so, how?**  (If it matters, I'm using JUnit 4.7, and it could be a hard sell to update to a different version)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A solution to the first issue is to move the logic into an extension of `org.junit.rules.ExternalResource` hooked up to the test via a [`@ClassRule`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/ClassRule.html), introduced in JUnit 4.9:

```
public class MyTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static final TestResources res = new TestResources();
    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // test logic here
    }
}

public class TestResources extends ExternalResource {
    protected void before() {
        // Setup logic that used to be in @BeforeClass
    }
    protected void after() {
        // Setup logic that used to be in @AfterClass
    }
}
```

In this way, the resources previously managed by the base class are moved out of the test class hierarchy and into more modular/consumable "resources" that can be created before a class runs and destroyed after a class runs.

As for solving both issues at the same time though - ie: having the same high level setup/teardown run as both part of an individual test and as part of a suite - there doesn't seem to be any specific built in support for this.  **However...**, *you could implement it yourself*:

Simply change the `@ClassRule` resource creation into a factory pattern that does reference counting internally to determine whether or not to create/destroy the resource.

For example (please note this is rough and might need some tweaks/error handling for robustness):

```
public class TestResources extends ExternalResource {
    private static int refCount = 0;

    private static TestResources currentInstance;

    public static TestResources getTestResources () {
        if (refCount == 0) {
            // currentInstance either hasn't been created yet, or after was called on it - create a new one
            currentInstance = new TestResources();
        }
        return currentInstance;
    }

    private TestResources() {
        System.out.println("TestResources construction");
        // setup any instance vars
    }

    protected void before() {
        System.out.println("TestResources before");
        try {
            if (refCount == 0) {
                System.out.println("Do actual TestResources init");
            }
        }
        finally {
            refCount++;
        }
    }

    protected void after() {
        System.out.println("TestResources after");
        refCount--;
        if (refCount == 0) {
            System.out.println("Do actual TestResources destroy");
        }
    }
}
```

Both your suite / test classes would just use the resource as a `@ClassResource` through the factory method:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({FooTest.class, BarTest.class})
public class MySuite {
    @ClassRule
    public static TestResources res = TestResources.getTestResources();
    @BeforeClass
    public static void suiteSetup() {
        System.out.println("Suite setup");
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void suiteTeardown() {
        System.out.println("Suite teardown");
    }
}
public class FooTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static TestResources res = TestResources.getTestResources();

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        System.out.println("testFoo");
    }
}
public class BarTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static TestResources res = TestResources.getTestResources();

    @Test
    public void testBar() {
        System.out.println("testBar");
    }
}
```

When running an individual test, the refcounting won't have any effect - the "actual init" and "actual teardown" will only happen once. When running through the suite, the suite will create the TestResource, and the individual tests will just reuse the already instantated one (the refcounting keeps it from being actually destroyed and recreated between tests in the suite).

Comment: I think your refCount system does not work. It'll get to zero after each class and delete your resource and then reinitialize it on the next class when calling the getTestResources(). I might be missing something, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The idea is that it can initialize when running an individual test or a suite of tests. **When running as a suite**, refCount is set to 1 by the suite `ClassRule`. Each test will change refCount to 2, then back to 1 when it's done. When the suite is done, it'll go to 0.  **When running as a test**, refCount is set to 1 by the individual test, then to 0 when the test completes.  The point is that the resource is only created and destroyed once in both ways of running.

Comment: Krease can we have @ClassRule inside TestResources?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`  **IN THE SUITE CLASS**.

This will run the methods before any of the test classes in the suite execute and after all the test classes finish (respectively)

This way you can run them only once.

```
//..usual @RunWith etc annotations here
public class MySuite{

@BeforeClass
public static void setup(){

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown(){

}

}
```

Comment: While this is nice if I only ever run the tests from a suite class, it won't work when I run the test individually (ie: in Eclipse, right click on the test and choose "Run as JUnit test") - the suite knows about the tests, but the tests don't know about the suite...

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar problem (Spring was not an option and i don't write TestSuites in maven projects) so i wrote simple junit runner to solve this problem.

You need to write `SharedResource` class and mark your test to require that resource.

```java
public class SampleSharedResource implements SharedResource {
    public void initialize() throws Exception {
    //initialize your resource
    }
}

@RunWith(JUnitSharedResourceRunner.class)
@JUnitSharedResourceRunner.WithSharedResources({SampleSharedResource.class})
public class SharedResourceRunnerATest {
    ...
```

Sources at https://github.com/eanlr/junit-shared-resources-runner