# Want to run many jUnit test classes with a shared @BeforeClass/@AfterClass and Spring App Context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am making some integration tests that load data into a remote test database before the integrations tests. However, it is a lot of data so I'd prefer to do it only once before all of my integrations tests.

I've gotten @BeforeClass/@AfterClass working with using either @RunWith(Suite.class) and JUnitCore.runClasses() to run all my test classes as a Suite. However, I am stuck on how to get Spring to Autowire resources that are needed for the setup and teardown. example:

```
public class AbstractTest {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("make tables");
    }
}
```

But sf is always null, because @BeforeClass needs to be run from a static context.
I have also tried using @ClassRule as shown here: [How to share JUnit BeforeClass logic among multiple test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391055/how-to-share-junit-beforeclass-logic-among-multiple-test-classes)
but with no change;

How do I get both the @BeforeClass/@AfterClass functionality for a suite of test classes and have Autowired resources in the @BeforeClass/@AfterClass methods? Getting this to run with @Parameterized as well would be even better.

Comment: Solution for null sf may be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425015/how-to-access-spring-context-in-junit-tests-annotated-with-runwith-and-context

Comment: If you are using `Spring Boot`, you should annotate the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`and `@SpringBootTest`, then Spring will deal with the dependencies for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the version of Spring that I'm locked into does not have @SpringBootTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringJUnit4ClassRunner calls BeforeClass  before autowired . Context is construced ,but not injected yet , by one be injected after calling BeforeClass   methods.

```
from RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks : 
     public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        for (FrameworkMethod before : befores) { -- call for BeforeClass methods
            before.invokeExplosively(target);
        }
        next.evaluate(); -- call DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener 
                          --where context is injected
}
```

You can try this (instead of @BeforeClass use afterPropertiesSet from InitializingBean - it's executed BeforeClass  call but before all test stat be executed)

```
public abstract class AbstractTest implements InitializingBean{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    //@BeforeClass
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("make tables");
}
```

or

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {

private static SessionFactory sf;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory (SessionFactory sf){
    AbstractTest.sf = sf;
    setup();
}

//@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("make tables");
}
}
```

In any case it be some work around as BeforeClass for tests classes is celled before spring context .

---

Variant 2 , updated

```
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {AbstractTest.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class AbstractTest extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

public static SessionFactory sf;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("make tables");
}

@Override
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    sf = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(SessionFactory.class);
    super.beforeTestClass(testContext);
}
}
```

Comment: And then all of my Test classes should inherit from this abstract class?

Comment: yes , nut only where you want to execute query ( . you want to do something custom . spring +junit give standart way for work with beforeclass methods

Comment: Right yeah, this is only for my integration tests. Is there a similar workaround for @AfterClass or will I have to do without?

Comment: I added second variant .I thought about one but in our project I chose first

Comment: Is there any benefit to the second Variant?

Comment: for @AfterClass  you shouldn't have any problem as conject is injected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147855/discussion-between-sbjavateam-and-oscar-courchaine).

Comment: second approach it's just another approach , I'm not 100% sure that transaction manager works correct  .

Comment: for first variant , you base test should implement spring initialization interface  and bit change junit lifecycle for beforClass , - you implement it in your way. with second approach you 100% follow junit logic but there is some "magic " that come from listener

Comment: Took me a while as I had to configure a lot behind the scenes, but I got variant 1, using InitializingBean, to work perfectly